# concatenate fields with zend_form

Tags: zend-framework

I'm using the zend framework with centurion and I'm having a problem with my form.  I have fields `num_ordre` and `code`, both of which are primary keys and I have columns in my table named `conca`, it's the concatenation of two fields, `num_ordre` and `code`.

My question is, in my method post, I want to test if the concatanation of `num_ordre` and `code` already exists in my database; but the problem is how to take a value of to fields before posting it.

This is my code

```
public function postAction(){

    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    $user = new Param_Model_DbTable_Verification();

    $form= $this->_getForm();
    $form->getElement('Num_ordre')->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists('verifications','Num_ordre'));
    $form->getElement('Num_ordre')->setRequired(true);
    $posts = $this->_request->getPost();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $row=$user->createRow();
            $row->code=$this->_getParam('code');
            $row->Num_ordre=$this->_getParam('Num_ordre');
            $row->Libelle_champ=$this->_getParam('Libelle_champ');
            $row->comparaison=$this->_getParam('comparaison');
            $row->formule=$this->_getParam('formule');
            $row->obligatoire=$this->_getParam('obligatoire');
            $row->Req_traduction=$this->_getParam('Req_traduction');
            $row->tolerance_erreur=$this->_getParam('tolerance_erreur');
            $row->Mess_erreur=$this->_getParam('Mess_erreur');
            $row->conca=$this->_getParam('Num_ordre').$this->_getParam('code');
            $row->save();
            if( isset ($posts['_addanother'])){
                $_form = $this->_getForm();
                $_form->removeElement('id');
                $this->_helper->redirector('new','admin-verification');
            }
            else
                $this->_helper->redirector(array('controller'=>'Admin-verification'));

            }else{
                parent::postAction();
            }
            }}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you just check it like this ?

```
public function postAction(){

    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(TRUE);
    $user = new Param_Model_DbTable_Verification();

    $form= $this->_getForm();
    $form->getElement('Num_ordre')->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists('verifications','Num_ordre'));
    $form->getElement('Num_ordre')->setRequired(true);
    $posts = $this->_request->getPost();
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        $mdl = new Model_Something();   //Call your model so you can test it
        //Add a condition here
        if ($form->isValid($formData) && $mdl->uniqueConcatenated($this->_getParam('num_ordre'), $this->_getParam('code')) {
            $row=$user->createRow();
            /**truncated, keep your existing code here**/
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your model Model_Something

```
public function uniqueConcatenated($numOrder, $code) {
  $concatenated = $numOrder.$code;
  //Check for the existence of a row with the concatenated field values
  $select = $this->select();
  $select->where('concatenatedField = '.$concatenated);
  $row = $this->fetchRow($select);
  return $row;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yes it's good and please how to set message if  values dont existe in database  its okey but if value existe in database   he tell me thais value is already in your database

Comment: thak you very much brother but i want to have message if value existe in database to telle me this value is a;lready in database choose another

Comment: Then you should look at the validator db_record_exists: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db

Answer (score 0):

You could manually call `isValid` on the validator:

```
$formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
    $formValues = $form->getValues();
    $uniqueValidator = new Zend_Validate_Db_NoRecordExists('verifications','conca');
    if ($uniqueValidator->isValid($formValues['Num_ordre'] . $formValues['Num_ordre'])) {
        // valid
    } else {
        // not unique
    }
}
```

*untested code*

Comment: thank you very much but the num-ordre is not necesary i just want to test  conca and conca is column in table who have value of num-ordre and code i juste want to khao how to take value of num ordre and code and concatanate after   test if value concatanate exist in database or not